# python ldap - add attribute value directly from file

Tags: python, django, ldap

Is there any way of adding LDAP attribute value directly from file?

I want to add jpegPhoto attribute to LDAP. Any combination of 'usual' OpenLDAP modification does not work, for example:

```
jpegPhoto: < file:///path/to/file   
jpegPhoto: file: /path/to/file   
jpegPhoto: /path/to/file
```

Here is what I try to do:

```
record = [
             ('objectclass', ['inetOrgPerson','organizationalPerson', 'person'),
             ('uid', ['jfoe@domain.com'] ),
             ('cn', ['Joe Foo'] ),
             ('sn', ['Foo'] ),
             ('givenName', ['Joe'] ),
             ('mail', ['jfoe@domain.com'] ),
             ('jpegPhoto', (any above combination here) )
         ]
l = ldap.initialize()
l.simple_bind_s()
l.add_s('uid=jfoe@domain.com,ou=tree,dc=organization', record)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first have to open the jpeg and read its binary data (a string) within python and store this string as the value of the jpegPhoto attribute on the LDAP server.
it works for me like this

```
#file to use
jpgFile = "testimage01.jpg"

#open the file with parameters read, binary(rb) and "read" the opened file
jpgBin = open(jpgFile,"rb").read()

record = [
              ('objectclass', ['inetOrgPerson','organizationalPerson', 'person'),
              ('uid', ['jfoe@domain.com'] ),
              ('cn', ['Joe Foo'] ),
              ('sn', ['Foo'] ),
              ('givenName', ['Joe'] ),
              ('mail', ['jfoe@domain.com'] ),
              ('jpegPhoto', [jpgBin] )
          ]

l = ldap.initialize()
l.simple_bind_s()
l.add_s('uid=jfoe@domain.com,ou=tree,dc=organization', record)
```